# setTimeout() doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a game with javascript, jquery, HTML, and CSS. It is a very simple game.:

- The blocks fade away, and the user has to click on them to keep them solid
- If one of the block fades completely away, you lose
- If you can keep them up for 10 seconds, you win.
- Beware that the blocks  fade quicker and quicker with each second.

This was was working fine until I tried to turn `win` into a function. Whenever I run the game, `preStart()` works fine, but then once `start()` begins, the game seems to call win() immediately, even though it's in a `setTimeout()`.

The javascript code is below. Just tell me if you need the HTML and/or CSS. I apologize in advance for the lengthy code, but I felt it might be easier if I showed all of it. I would also like to thank you in advance for taking the time to answer my question thoughtfully and nicely.

```
var red = document.getElementById("red");
var blue = document.getElementById("blue");
var green = document.getElementById("green");
var text = document.getElementById("text");

var score = 0;
var fadeRate = 0.01;
var started = false;

var rop = 1.0;
var bop = 1.0;
var gop = 1.0;

function preStart() {
  clearInterval(win);
  reset();
  if (started == false) {
    started = true;
    setTimeout(function() {text.style.left = '300px'; text.innerHTML = "3";}, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {text.innerHTML = "3 2";}, 1100);
    setTimeout(function() {text.innerHTML = "3 2 1";}, 2100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      text.style.left = '350px';
      text.innerHTML = "Go!";
      start();
    }, 3100);
  }
}

function start() {
  fade = setInterval(function() {
    rop = rop - fadeRate;
    red.style.opacity = rop;
    bop = bop - fadeRate;
    blue.style.opacity = bop;
    gop = gop - fadeRate;
    green.style.opacity = gop;

    if (rop <= 0 || bop <= 0 || gop <= 0) {lose();}
  }, 50);

  speedUp = setInterval(function() {
    fadeRate = fadeRate + 0.01;
  }, 1000);

  setInterval(win(), 10000);
}

function redClick() {
  score = score + rop * 10;
  rop = 1.0;
  red.style.opacity = rop;
}

function blueClick() {
  score = score + bop * 10;
  bop = 1.0;
  blue.style.opacity = bop;
}

function greenClick() {
  score = score + gop * 10;
  gop = 1.0;
  green.style.opacity = gop;
}

function lose() {
  clearInterval(fade);
  clearInterval(speedUp);
  clearInterval(win);
  setTimeout(function() {text.style.left = '150px'; text.innerHTML = "You lose!";}, 100);
  setTimeout(function() {
    text.style.left = '250px';
    text.innerHTML = "Retry?";
    started = false;
    reset();
  }, 2100);
}

function win() {
  clearInterval(fade);
  clearInterval(speedUp);
  clearInterval(win);
  setTimeout(function() {text.style.left = '175px'; text.innerHTML = "You win!";}, 100);
  score = Math.floor(score);
  setTimeout(function() {text.style.left = '100px'; text.innerHTML = "Score: " + score;}, 2100);
  setTimeout(function() {
    text.style.left = '250px';
    text.innerHTML = "Retry?"
    started = false;
    reset();
  }, 4100);
}

function reset() {
  score = 0;
  fadeRate = 0.01;
  rop = 1.0;
  bop = 1.0;
  gop = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Because you are calling win right away.... `setInterval(win(), 10000);`

Comment: `clearInterval(win);` ?

Answer (score 4):

You are ***invoking*** win when setting it as a callback in you setInterval by putting open and closed parentheses ( "`()`" ) after the function

Change this:

```
setInterval( win(), 10000);
```

To this ( *removed parentheses to avoid **invoking** win):*

```
setInterval(win, 10000);
```

In addition, you seem to be trying to clear the interval by passing in function `win` rather than the integer that is returned when setting the interval:

```
// set win to be invoked every 10000 ms
var intervID = setInterval(win, 10000);

// clear the interval above and thus stop it from
// invoking win any further
clearInterval(intervID);
```

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks. I feel like such a dummy. Thanks though, it seems to be working, so I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @DallasWhite glad I could help. Made another quick note regarding clearing the interval too.

Comment: @DallasWhite That's one of the mistakes nearly everyone makes once; it's easy to remember it once you know how to fix it, though.